# How to put the outcome of a loop as values of a Dataframe column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, loops

I am running a code with the python RegEx module. In particular, I want to extract hashtags from the text of some tweets. I have a Dataframe containing various columns of which 'text' is one.
My code is following:

```
`import re
spilthash = re.compile(r"#(\w+)")

def split_tags(s):
    return spilthash.findall(s)

for t in df['text']:
    tags = split_tags(t)
    print(tags)'
```

The code runs perfectly and outputs the hashtags of each row as a list. For example, the first three rows' output is the following:['Sozialismus', 'Mauerbau']['Covid_19', 'Testpflicht', 'coronapandemie', 'Impfpflicht'][]

I want to amend my code to save this output as a column in the original Dataframe. That is, I should get: df['Hashtags'] = [{'Sozialismus', 'Mauerbau'}, {'Covid_19'....}, ......]

I tried different codes with append but it simply puts the entire outcome as one list, where one can't differentiate between the rows. For, example, when I tried the following:

```
import re
spilthash = re.compile(r"#(\w+)")

def split_tags(s):
    return spilthash.findall(s)

hashtags = []
for t in df['text']:
    tags = split_tags(t)
   
    for x in tags:
        hashtags.append(x)
```

Output: ['Sozialismus','Mauerbau','Covid_19','Testpflicht',.......]

I would appreciate any help with the code.

Comment: The snippet you suggested actually helped fix another issue that I was facing in a bigger dataset, where it was not recognizing the datatype as str. However, the code doesn't run with expand=False. It gets a 'do not recognize an operand' error.

Comment: Sorry, the `findall` has no `expand` attribute, it is `Series.str.extract` attribute. the findall does not need it, `df['text'].str.findall(r'#(\w+)')`